# Getting memory leaks when using camera integration code in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, camera

I'm doing an application which allows user to take a picture from camera or select picture from library.
I'm using the code

```
- (BOOL)startCameraPickerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)delegateObject  
{  
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
  {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]autorelease];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

  }

return YES;  
}
```

I'm getting memory leak when I'm running this application. I'm running this application on 3.0.

Guys Please help me.

Comment: -1. Where's the code that hides the controller? What do you do with the returned image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `[controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];` do `[picker release];` and get rid of the autorelease when you init the UIImagePickerController. That may work?

Comment: glad that worked! I feel like objective C loves to throw curve balls at me all the time. :3